# Очередь проверок может показать давно удалённые вопросы

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, закрытие-вопросов, очередь-проверок

9 ноября в [очереди на закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close) увидел [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458916/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE), который был уже закрыт и удалён 16 октября.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почти уверен, что вам попалась метапроверка (проверка проверяющего). Материал для них как раз набирается из таких давно закрытых вопросов. Это (почти) гарантирует, что вопрос действительно подлежал закрытию.

Comment: Вероятно. В сторону: "ловушка" наверно слишком негативно. Можно слово "аудит" использовать.

Comment: @jfs: переформулировал, «ловушка» действительно может быть непонятна и негативно воспринята.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Уточнил. Действительно, с большой вероятностью, старые вопросы в очереди проверки – это аудит.

Comment: После проверок же выводится сообщение, что она пройдена, либо не пройдена.

Comment: И мне вариант "ловушка" больше нравится.

Comment: @Qwertiy: (1) если бы я увидел бы сообщение, то и вопроса бы не было в первую очередь. (2) "ловушка" -- подразумевает недоверие: лучше избегать обвинений в сторону активных добровольцев. "аудит" -- более нейтрально: все ошибаются и проверки могут помочь правила более последовательно усиливать.